# What is unprotected instances in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just got a word in below link that aws have unprotected instance what is it mean in actualy?

Reference link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html

Answer (score 2):

When using autoscaling you can protect instances from termination during scale in events by selecting them in the Auto Scaling Console and then choosing Instance Protection from the Actions menu.

> You might want to do this for several reasons. First, an instance
>   might be handling a long-running work task, perhaps pulled from an SQS
>   queue. Protecting the instance from termination will avoid wasted
>   work. Second, the instance might serve a special purpose within the
>   group. It could be the master node of a Hadoop cluster or a “canary”
>   that flags the entire group of instances as up and running.
>
> In most cases, you will want to leave at least one instance in each of
>   your auto scaling groups unprotected. If all of the instances are
>   protected, no scale in action will be taken.

[Link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-protection-for-auto-scaling/)